# Reducing Hamiltonian path to TREFOIL

Tags: np-complete, hamiltonian-path

HAMTREFOIL = {(G,s,t,u,v) | there exist paths s->t, s->u, s->v such that every vertex(except s) belongs to one of the paths}

I want to prove that HAMTREFIOL is NP-complete by reducing Hamiltonian path to it but I am stuck in the construction part.
Any tips or solutions would be great.
Thank you.